# Is iPad Simulator on this version of XCode 4 buggy?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Look at this film for proof
http://vimeo.com/39844347

compare to this one
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lJkRiJj4G0

Same code but not same result. So is some versions of iPad simulator buggy ?

Comment: I encountered some bug regarding the launch screen, but UIWebView seems to be okay for me.

Comment: Is it on iphone or Ipad ? Did you look at the 2 videos ? The procedure is the same but results completely different.

Comment: yes I did take a look, otherwise I wouldn't mention UIWebView. I didn't know the cause though.

Answer (score -1):

A simulator is just that a simulation of the software and some of the hardware. This does leave open the potential for 'bugs' to exist. That is why I always test in simulator and on a real device. This way you can be 100% sure of the results you are getting. I have seen some people develop an iPad app without ever having a physical iPad. This is just leaving them self open to so many problems. I would say overall the simulator works pretty damn well and I have noticed very few things that simulator screws up.

Comment: Did you look at the video ? This is the most basic HELLO WORLD UIWebView app you can do and it desn't even work ? And on one simulator of Xcode 4 it works, on some next version it doesn't ? Do you think it's normal ?

Comment: Yes I did, my logic still stands. You think because you found one bug in the software that this invalidates the entire simulation software. Thousands of people have successfully used it to create hundreds of thousands of apps. Does that mean that because iOS has bugs means its buggy and pos, i dont think so. If you really think its so buggy then stop using it.

Comment: It's not a small bug: it's a fundamental bug.

Comment: @atrljoe , FYI, the iOS Simulator is an API simulator, it's not a hardware simulator.